# Convert excel data to JSON format

Tags: node.js, angular

I am developing application using Angular 2 and Node.js. In my application I have document upload like excel documents. I need to convert excel data to JSON format. Is it possible to do with angular 2 Or do i need to use Node.js?

I'm really got stuck in this conversion.

Comment: Is the excel data in CSV format or a regular Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Is it possible to manage both formats?

Comment: CSV data would be easy to do, excel format, which contains formulas, formatting, code and anything else is at least very difficult to convert to JSON and probably not worth doing. You perhaps need to revisit why you need to convert this.

Comment: I am uploading excel file to Amazon s3 i need to convert . That excel file data to JSON format